# Error in trigger - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

eu criei a seguinte trigger, mas ela ta com um erro de sintaxe que não to conseguindo encontrar.

O erro é o seguinte

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'on rev_reviews AFTER INSERT AS BEGIN DECLARE
>   @totalItens int
>       DECLARE @revis' at line 1

a trigger é esta:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertReview 
on rev_reviews
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @totalItens int
    DECLARE @revisado varchar(4)
    DECLARE @countRevisado int
    DECLARE @ean varchar(4)
    DECLARE @countEan int


    select count(1) into @totalItens from rev_reviews where task_id = new.task_id
    select @revisado = revisado, @ean = ean_existe from rev_reviews where id = new.id    

    select @countRevisado = count(1) from rev_reviews where task_id = new.task_id AND Revisado LIKE @revisado

    select @countEan = count(1) from rev_reviews where task_id = new.task_id AND ean_existe LIKE @ean;

    CASE
        WHEN @ean == 'Sim' THEN
            CASE
                WHEN @revisado == 'Nao' 
                    THEN update rev_tasks set totalItens = @totalItens, totalPen = @countRevisado, totalEan = @countEan where id = new.task_id
                WHEN @revisado == 'Sim' 
                    THEN update rev_tasks set totalItens = @totalItens, totalRev = @countRevisado, totalEan = @countEan where id = new.task_id
                WHEN @revisado == 'NR' 
                    THEN update rev_tasks set totalItens = @totalItens, totalNr = @countRevisado, totalEan = @countEan where id = new.task_id
                WHEN @revisado == 'Aut' 
                    THEN update rev_tasks set totalItens = @totalItens, totalAut = @countRevisado, totalEan = @countEan where id = new.task_id
            END
        ELSE
            CASE
                WHEN @revisado == 'Nao' 
                    THEN update rev_tasks set totalItens = @totalItens, totalPen = @countRevisado, totalNEan = @countEan where id = new.task_id
                WHEN @revisado == 'Sim' 
                    THEN update rev_tasks set totalItens = @totalItens, totalRev = @countRevisado, totalNEan = @countEan where id = new.task_id
                WHEN @revisado == 'NR' 
                    THEN update rev_tasks set totalItens = @totalItens, totalNr = @countRevisado, totalNEan = @countEan where id = new.task_id
                WHEN @revisado == 'Aut' 
                    THEN update rev_tasks set totalItens = @totalItens, totalAut = @countRevisado, totalNEan = @countEan where id = new.task_id
            END
    END
END
```

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Eai, jovem. Aqui no [pt.so] só aceitamos perguntas em português. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta e traduzi-la para mantê-la aqui, mas, se preferir, pode postar a mesma pergunta no [so].

Answer (score 1):

Ola,
segundo a documentação do MariaDB:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-trigger/#examples

a Criação dessa trigger esta incorreta, pois muda as ordens dos parâmetros iniciais:
No Maria DB as ordens do parâmetro de create são invertido, sendo o `After insert`antes do nome da tabela e nao depois como na maioria dos bancos

```
///seu
CREATE TRIGGER insertReview 
on rev_reviews
AFTER INSERT 
AS
///correto
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER insertReview 
  AFTER INSERT ON rev_reviews
```

Comment: Eu não entendi qual é a solução?

Comment: inverte AFTER INSERT antes do nome da tabela

Comment: Compreendi @FelipeEleiterio, mas eu sugiro editar sua resposta para deixar isso claro, sem depender de análise em outro lugar. Apesar de que o link da documentação do MariaDB falando sobre isso é muito útil!

Comment: Melhorei a resposta ... deu certo ?

Comment: Está muiiito melhor! Apesar de que eu estava um pouco desatento, você tinha respondido, mas muitos outros podem ler superficialmente também e não compreender o que quis dizer. Obrigado!

Comment: Olá Felipe, alterei aqui e o erro continua o mesmo, acredito que o erro é mais embaixo, literalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Galera consegui resolver aqui,
estava faltando o DELIMITER $$,
com o DELIMITER pode-se colocar o ';' necessários.
além disso o DECLARE não possui o '@' e os selects quando feito para guardar em uma variavel, deve-se usar a palavra INTO

EX:

```
 select count(1) into @totalItens from rev_reviews where task_id = new.task_id
```

esses foram os erros identificados.